# What action.accept(val) in spliterator does

Tags: java, spliterator

I don't understand what action.accept(val) does, already searched about it, I understand it has to be done, just don't know why.
here is a simple example I don't understand:

```
public class CachedSpliterator <T> extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator 
{
    Spliterator<T> spliterator;
    int index;
    ArrayList<T> cache;

public CachedSpliterator(Spliterator<T> spliterator, ArrayList<T> cache) {
    super(spliterator.characteristics(), 0);
    this.spliterator=spliterator;
    index=0;
    this.cache=cache;
}

public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer action){         
    if(index<cache.size()){ 
        action.accept(cache.get(index));       
        index++;                                
        return true;                            
    }
    else{
        return spliterator.tryAdvance(val->{    

            cache.add(val);
            index++;                            
            action.accept(val);
        });
    }
}
```

So in this code for example I understand that we have a consumer that consumes every element from a source (in this case the spliterator) and every element has to be accepted by the action.
So in my mind the action is the cache.add(val) and the increment of variable index, i don't understand why the last line (action.accept(val)) has to be written at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the `action` is a user defined function to execute on the data and meant for the user of `CachedSpliterator`. the increment and adding to cache is part of the inner logic of the class.
For example:

```java
CachedSpliterator spliterator = new CachedSpliterator(...);
spliterator.tryAdvance(item -> {
    // Will execute this code on every item from the source
    // Can perform any logic here, like save to a database
    db.save(item);   
});
```